# Any Issues Between CS6 Flash Pro and Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs6

I am trying to follow this guide: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-flash-professional-cs5/using-flash-pro-and-flash-builder-together/

While using CS6 Flash Pro and Flash Builder 4.5.

The issue I am having is my Flash Builder code doesn't seem to have any effect. I did everything the guide with the only variation being the names I used and button position.

The code I ended up with:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class UntitledMessage extends MovieClip
    {
        public function UntitledMessage()
        {
            super();

            var icon:btnDontKnow = new btnDontKnow();
            icon.x = 0;
            icon.y = 0;
            addChild(icon);

            var btnLabel:TextField = new TextField();
            btnLabel.text = "Play Intro";
            btnLabel.x = 250;
            btnLabel.y = 275;
            addChild(btnLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source code seems to be ignored, try deliberately inserting a syntax error. Remove a curly brace or something similar.

If there are still no errors, are compiling from a .fla and this is supposed to be the root element, I would try checking the Document Class property in the .fla file. It's under *Publish* in the *Properties* tab in Flash CS6. It should state that UntitledMessage is the Document Class and the file has been found.

Also make sure you are editing the file that is actually being read and not a copy. Stupid but common mistake.